# MediaElement.js - how to autoplay next audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

How to play next audio tag when the current one ends? I am using plagin's MediaElement.js.

```
<div class="audio-player track quotations">
  <audio src="http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/9ucf2r3yo6/chasing_cars_cover_chris_-    _for_hollie_s_cover.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">
  </audio>
</div>
<div class="audio-player track quotations">
  <audio src="http://k004.kiwi6.com/hotlink/vvy55kc7c5/new_distance.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">
  </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `ended` eventlistener to the `audio` tag, and automatically play the next one. For example;

```
    var selector = 'audio'; // CHANGE as per your requirements
    var audios = $(selector), len = audios.length, i = 0;
    audios.bind('ended', function(e){
        i++;
        if(i === len)   i=0;
        audios[i].play();
    });
```